# Hi-lock code syntax

Tags: font-lock, hi-lock

I write Hi-lock code at the beginning of tex and org buffers, but it doesn't always behave as I expect it to. What does the number 0 mean in the following? What does it mean when it is 1, instead?

```
% Hi-lock: (("[HH]umpty" (0 (quote hi-red-b) prepend)))
% Hi-lock: (("[DD]umpty" (0 (quote hi-green) prepend)))
```

Comment: Extra plus for quoting the face name and for using `prepend` rather than `t`. When not quoting the face name, font-lock interpret as a variable name which is bound the the name of the face, which is slower. `prepend` is better than `t` since it adds face properties rather than replacing them -- concretely, if the text has a background and you add a face that only define a foreground, the original background is retained.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It refers to the regexp group that should be highlighted. 0 means the entire regexp. 1 means the first group etc.

A group is specified using `\(` and `\)`. For example:

```
"\\(Humpty\\)\\(Dumpty\\)" (1 'hi-red-b prepend) (2 'hi-green prepend))
```

In this example, Humpty is subgroup 1 and Dumpty 2. They will be colored red and green, respectively.

Note that regexp:s are written using elisp strings, so the backslash needs to be quoted -- in other words the string `"\\("` yields the regepx `\(`.

This is described in the elisp manual, in the section [Search Based Fontification](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Search_002dbased-Fontification.html). The format typically used is the `(matcher highlighters ...)` form, with highlighters on the form *subexp-highlighter*, documented above.

Comment: @Drew, good idea, I've updated the answer.

Comment: @Lindydancer, helpful, thank you very much. Interestingly, when I do this :     `% Hi-lock: (("[HH]umpty" (0 (quote hi-red-b) prepend)))`
`% Hi-lock: (("[DD]umpty" (1 (quote hi-green) prepend)))` Dumpty falls over, and when Dumpty falls over, Humpty falls over too, and so do a lot of others, but not necessary all of them. But this is good. I may have some follow up.

Comment: @seeker, You can't use `1` here since there is no regexp subgroup in the regexp. Either use `0` or add a group using something like `"outside\\(this-is-group-1\\)outside-again"`.

Comment: I think I'm getting it. Thank you.